# Separate array in sub arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this following array in C#:

```
string[][] arrayofArrays = getArray();
```

I know that the arrays which are in arrayofArrays have a length of 2. My question is the following: **is it possible to "split" or to "separate" the principal array in two arrays?**

Thanks.

EDIT: *I would like to know if there is a way which is already implemented in C#, I know how to do that with an algorithm.*

EDIT 2: here is an example of what I need:

```
// here are the data:
string[][] arrayofArrays = {{"1", "a"}, {"2", "b"}, {"3", "c"}};

//here is what I need as output:
string[] array1 = {"1", "2", "3"};
string[] array2 = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

Comment: As a declaration, or as a procedure/algorithm?

Comment: Split it how? Based on what criteria?

Comment: You have a 2D array and you want to separate it into 2 single dimension array ?

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way which is already implemented in C#, I know how to do that with an algorithm.

Comment: Please could you provide examples of the data returned by the `getArray()` method and the corresponding expected content of the `arrayOfArrays` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can do this:

```
string[] firstArray=Array.ConvertAll(arrayofArrays,a => a[0]);
string[] secondArray=Array.ConvertAll(arrayofArrays,a => a[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

And one more variant:

```
var array1 = arrayOfArrays.Select(a => a[0]).ToArray();
var array2 = arrayOfArrays.Select(a => a[1]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this LINQ query should do what you want:

```
int numArrays = 2;
string[][] arrayofTwoArrays = arrayofArrays
    .Select((arr, index) => new { arr, index })
    .GroupBy(x => (x.index + 1) % numArrays, x => x.arr)
    .Select(g => g.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```